# nodemon installation problem in nodejs using npm

Tags: nodemon

npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`

npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin; ENOENT
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-21T00_36_51_224Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

first show us how you are installing it, and try run it as admin.